# How to create more than one subdirectory using ZSH? (on a Debian machine)

Tags: zsh, brace-expansion

I am trying to do this in ZSH:

```
mkdir -p static/{css, js, img}
```

but my ZSH is nagging a bit:

```
zsh: parse error near `}'
```

What am I doing wrong here and what would be the proper way to do this type of expansion? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the spaces:

```
mkdir -p static/{css,js,img}
```

(See [Brace Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) in the Zsh documentation for details.)